# How to get the text for PHP breadcrumbs?

Tags: php, html, navigation, breadcrumbs

I have made a simple PHP "Breadcrumbs" class, that can convert a path like this:

```
some_folder/subfolder/page.php
```

into this:

```
Home > some_folder > subfolder > page
```

where each element links to the appropriate page. However, what I really want is to get the text for these breadcrumbs from somewhere other than the filename, so that it can look more like this:

```
Home > Cool Stuff > Animals > Spiders
```

I thought of using HTML < meta > tags but:

1. I don't know if this is efficient
2. This won't work for directories, only pages

So, can anyone tell me a good way of doing this? (Thanks!)

Comment: It all depends on what your system looks like, where information is entered and so on, but you could store names in database.

Comment: Yeah, you need some sort of mapping for text you want -> folder/file names.  This could be stored in a DB, text file, or hard coded.  This way you have access to the actual link, which would be the folder/file and you could put that as the href attribute, and place the text in the tag.

Comment: You'd have to go the database route or a single index page route. If you locate it on the page itself and need to change `Cool Stuff` to `New Stuff` you would need to change every child page. Meta data might work, but the child page would have to look at the meta data for each parent page to build the crumb.

Comment: I am using a FrontController pattern, if that's what you mean? It would be easy for me to store the mappings in an array as @TunaMaxx demonstrated, but I'm worried about scalability, and to me it doesn't seem like a very clean separation of code and data.

Comment: @Dan my sample it's not a completely optimized example on purpose; it was a general idea of what needs to be done. How it fits in your app is up to you. The point is, you will **have to map path segments to custom strings**. Your breadcrumb class can't read your mind to figure out what you want; you have to tell it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure there is an easier way of doing this, but something along these lines works. Just modify the $trail array for you directory to breadcrumb link title changes:

```
// Alter this array as needed to convert path items in to
// breadcrumb link titles
$trail = array(
    'path' => 'Cool Stuff',
    'to' => 'Animals',
    'a' => 'Spiders'
);

// You could grab this automatically with $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']
$url = 'http://example.com/path/to/more/deadly/a/black_widow.php';

$parts         = parse_url($url);
$path          = pathinfo($parts['path']);
$segments      = explode('/', trim($path['dirname'],'/'));

$breadcrumbs[] = '<a href="/">Home</a>';
$crumb_path    = '';

foreach ($segments as $segment)
{
    $crumb_path .= '/' . $segment;

    $value = (array_key_exists($segment, $trail)) ? $trail[$segment] : ucfirst($segment);

    $breadcrumbs[] = '<a href="' . $crumb_path . '">' . $value . '</a>';
}

$breadcrumbs[] = ucwords(str_replace('_', ' ', $path['filename']));
$breadcrumbs   = implode(' > ', $breadcrumbs);

echo $breadcrumbs;
```

This will create a breadcrumb string like:

[Home](http://example.com) > [Cool Stuff](http://example.com/path) > [Animals](http://example.com/path/to) > [More](http://example.com/path/to/more) > [Deadly](http://example.com/path/to/more/deadly) > [Spiders](http://example.com/path/to/more/deadly/a) > Black Widow

With an HTML source like:

```
<a href="/">Home</a> > 
<a href="/path">Cool Stuff</a> > 
<a href="/path/to">Animals</a> > 
<a href="/path/to/more">More</a> > 
<a href="/path/to/more/deadly">Deadly</a> > 
<a href="/path/to/more/deadly/a">Spiders</a> > 
Black Widow
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it was very helpful. I guess this is the "hard-coded" route @czobrisky mentioned. Bearing in mind scalability and efficiency, would you say that the best way of storing the $trail mapping is in a PHP array like this?

Comment: Unless your directory structure exactly matches what you want the breadcrumb links to look like, you will have to create some sort of mapping between the two. Whether that is in a manually built array, or retrieved from a database, at some point you have to tell your app that the `/some_folder` directory should be represented as "Cool Stuff" for example. As for scalability and efficiency, use something  like `$url = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` instead of my hardcoded path in the example, and it is hands free. If there are matching keys in the array, they will be replaced by the values.